# How can I use PHP to find a row in a MySQL DB table and insert just one value?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, I know I can make a new row and enter values into all fields doing this:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( "id77" ,"some value" )');
```

Assuming the name of the first field ("id77") is "myID" and the name of the second field ("some value") is "foo"...

How can I use PHP find the row with myID = id77 and change the "foo" value to "bar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE table_name SET foo = 'bar' WHERE myID = 77");
```

I assume that you are using an integer (77) for your IDs instead of a string value ("id77").

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE ... WHERE.

You should read some books on MySQL first.

Comment: Yes, that worked, thanks for the answer. :) Eventually, I will read the book; however, I do not have time to do that this morning.

Comment: ;) You are welcome. If you have no books, MySQL online documentation is also ok.